# Change Object's Scale Smoothly with Swipe

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote the code below to change an object's scale (X axis) with mouse swipe, it works but it's not smooth, **how can I smooth it?**

**Script:**

```
Vector3 newScale;
private float _previousSwipePosition;
private float newPosition;

if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        _previousSwipePosition = Input.mousePosition.x;

        if (newPosition != _previousSwipePosition)
        {
            if (newPosition - _previousSwipePosition < -2)
            {
                if (transform.localScale.x <= 1.4f)
                {
                    newScale = transform.localScale;
                    newScale.x += 0.06f;
                    transform.localScale = newScale;
                }
            }
            else if (newPosition - _previousSwipePosition > 2)
            {
                if (transform.localScale.x >= 0.2f)
                {
                    newScale = transform.localScale;
                    newScale.x -= 0.06f;
                    transform.localScale = newScale;
                }
            }
        }

        newPosition = Input.mousePosition.x;
    }
```

Comment: `newScale.x += 0.06f*Time.deltaTime`
`newScale.x -= 0.06f*Time.deltaTime`
try this

Comment: why is `newPositon` the mouse's x position on the previous frame and `_previousSwipePosition` the x position on the current frame? Isn't that backwards?

Comment: @taik Did you find a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` to get smoothed scale of how much the mouse has moved in the last frame. Multiply that by a speed parameter.

Get the power of 2 by that product to get how much to change the current scale. Then, change the scale and clamp it:

```
public float scaleSpeed = 1f;

// ...

    // ignore first frame mouse is pressed
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        float scaleFactor = Mathf.Pow(2f, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") 
                                          * scaleSpeed);

        float newX = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localScale.x * scaleFactor, 0.2f, 1.4f);
    
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                newX, 
                transform.localScale.y, 
                transform.localScale.z);
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is smooth but there's a problem, when you click (first click without moving the finger) the object scale change immediately(depend on click area, if click right of screen the object scale up, and the opposite also), than when moving it scale properly. How to solve that?

Comment: @Taik I added `&& !Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` to the `if` expression to skip the block when the mouse is first pressed. Try that.

Comment: Coming back, I realized multiplying by deltaTime is innapropriate here

Answer (score 0):

Use Time.deltaTime to smooth

```
    Vector3 newScale;
    private float _previousSwipePosition;
    private float newPosition;
    private float speed = 6f;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if (transform.localScale.x <= 1.4f)
            {
                newScale = transform.localScale;
                newScale.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.localScale = newScale;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.B))
        {
            if (transform.localScale.x >= 0.2f)
            {
                newScale = transform.localScale;
                newScale.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.localScale = newScale;
            }
        }
    }
```